# Error: Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the "credential" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token

Tags: node.js, express

```
    const admin = require('firebase-admin');
    require('dotenv').config()
    // const serviceAccount = require("../service-account-file.json");
    const check = process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS;
    //GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/byordani93/tuDiagram/service-account-file.json"
    console.log(check, 'mate')

    admin.initializeApp({
      projectId: 'tudiagram',
      credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault(check),
      databaseURL: 'https://tudiagram.firebaseio.com'
    });

    module.exports = admin;
```

then msg

```
> (node:3218) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Credential
> implementation provided to initializeApp() via the "credential"
> property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the
> following error: "Error fetching access token: Error while making
> request: The "options.agent" property must be one of type Agent-like
> Object, undefined, or false. Received type string. Error code:
> ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE".
>
```

> I tried making the env value a string and not a string as well as
>   checking to see if the process.env was being detected and still
>   nothing not sure at this point I have googled to no avail please give
>   some pointers or tips **hint hint maybe a solution haha :)

Comment: Twas the admin.credential.applicationDefault(check) I changed it to admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount) ---> const serviceAccount = require("../server/../service-account-file.json");

Comment: I have a similar issue described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68556603/unable-to-call-firebase-function-from-react-js-application?noredirect=1#comment121162862_68556603  do you think you could help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this one

```
    import * as firebase  from 'firebase-admin';
    const  serviceAccount = require("../../serviceAccountKey.json")
    
    firebase.initializeApp({
      credential: firebase.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
      databaseURL: 'https://xxxxxx.firebaseio.com'
    });
```

changing the **applicationDefault** to **cert**

Comment: what's the difference? (this worked for me too)

Comment: I have a similar issue described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68556603/unable-to-call-firebase-function-from-react-js-application?noredirect=1#comment121162862_68556603  do you think you could help?

Answer (score 0):

Our team also get similar message error.
So, we just fix as below:

1. Remove function in dashboard firebase.
2. Install Node.js
3. Install `firebase-functions`, `firebase-admin`, `firebase-tools`
   Ref: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started
4. Config dependencies in package.json, config the same version firebase-admin, firebase-functions as version you can see in step 3.
5. Remove yarn.lock
6. Deploy function.