# Unable to call Firebase function from React.js application

Tags: firebase

I have a React.js application powered by a number of [Firebase functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) and [real time database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database) standing behind them. It has been working without any issue for the past 2-3 months and now I am getting a warning on the functions logs which says that:

```
@firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: {"code":"app/invalid-credential","message":"Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the \"credential\" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: \"Failed to parse access token response: Error: Server responded with status 404.\"."}
```

The way I initialize firebase from my React.js application looks like this:
[image]

I have double-checked everything standing behind **process.env** and it seems to be as expected. The website written in React.js in hosted under the [Firebase hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting).

And this is how Firebase functions connect to Admin SDK:
[image]

I am not sure what would be the issue here. Nothing has changes in the code base from our side. Not sure if Firebase changed something internally that we need to consider.

Comment: Have you checked this [Github issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1708) ?

Comment: @Dharmaraj I saw this one but in my case I don't have such thing as a "service account key json" or "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"

Comment: The error seems to be in Cloud function and not your Reactapp.. The Admin SDK in Cloud function uses Admin SDK. Does the same error exist when your deploy the function?

Comment: @Dharmaraj I re-deployed the function a couple of times without any issue but the problem still exists

Comment: How are you initializing Admin SDK in Cloud function? Can you share that part of code? You don't need to pass any arguments if its in a cloud function.

Comment: @Dharmaraj I just updated my question with a code snippet to show how I do it.

Comment: Try removing the config. If you are using cloud function you don't need to pass any credential yourself. It'll use Application Default Credentials. Just `admin.initializeApp()` should do.

Comment: I am not sure how to approach it. Do I need to change something only on the server side (cloud functions/node.js)? This is a production issue and I need to carefully handle it.

Comment: Yes just try removing the content param from initializeApp method.

Comment: You mean functions.config().firebase?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235378/discussion-between-dharmaraj-and-user2128702).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What solved the issue for me was to go to the [google cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard?project=visitor-app-pass-it-on) (where Firebase functions are also available). Then I opened one of the failing cloud functions and I navigated to

```
My_Function_Name/Edit/RUNTIME, BUILD AND CONNECTIONS SETTINGS/RUNTIME SERVICE ACCOUNT/
```

[image]

And then I noticed there that for all of my functions it was selected **App Engine Default Service Account** instead of **Firebase Admin SDK**. I never explicitly set the runtime to this option. So, when I brought it back to **Firebase Admin SDK** the error was gone I was able to use the application once again.